# SQL UPDATE-else-INSERT an Excel "table"

Tags: sql, excel, insert-update, vba

This question is building from a previous question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34257904/vba-sql-update-insert-select-to-from-excel-worksheet/34259616#34259616) - please read it as it has most of the details and background details).  The only difference in the code between what's linked to and here is the `qry` string (given below).  Let me know if more detail is needed in this post.

**My question: *How do I UPDATE if able, otherwise Insert the new record?***  I've tried several variations, but doing this through Excel-VBA is proving...difficult.  For the sake of simplicity, I'll keep my examples down to two (the two that seem to be most efficient).

**1)** Through troubleshooting I've determined that this is failing due to the `@@ROWCOUNT`, but I can't figure out the variable name (if it exists in this context).

```
qry = "UPDATE <tbl> " & vbNewLine & _
      "SET empName='<name>', empDay=CDate('<date>'), inTime=CDate('<in>'), outTime=CDate('<out>'), " & _
          "vac=CBool('<vac>'), sales=CDbl(<sales>) " & vbNewLine & _
      "WHERE empName='<name>' AND empDay=CDate('<date>') " & vbNewLine & _
      "IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 " & vbNewLine & _
      "  INSERT INTO <tbl> (empName, empDay, inTime, outTime, vac, sales)" & vbNewLine & _
      "  VALUES (CStr('<name>'), CDate('<date>'), CDate('<in>'), CDate('<out>'), " & _
            "CBool('<vac>'), CDbl(<sales>));" & vbNewLine & _
      "END;"
```

**2)** This *almost* works and only complains of missing the ";" at the end of the SQL statement (which is clearly there).  The parens seem to match up as well.

```
qry = "INSERT INTO <tbl> (empName, empDay, inTime, outTime, vac, sales)" & vbNewLine & _
      "VALUES (CStr('<name>'), CDate('<date>'), CDate('<in>'), CDate('<out>'), " & _
            "CBool('<vac>'), CDbl(<sales>))" & vbNewLine & _
      "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (empName='<name>' AND empDay=CDate('<date>'));"
```

Comment: If using Windows Jet/ACE SQL Engine, its SQL dialect does not support multiple action queries in one statement. Conditionally separate by a lookup in VBA and call either accordingly. And it's worth mentioning again -[Excel is not a database](https://www.google.com/#q=excel+is+not+a+database).

Comment: @Parfait Indeed it's not. Thanks for once again helping out on this. These limitations certainly keep things...interesting.  I'd prefer a proper database with a custom WPF front-end, but this is what I need to work within.